# Replace /yyy.php? in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

So, basically I have a ton of addresses going something like

http://localhost/yyy.php?etcetcetc where the etc is replaceable for many different pages.

I need a rule for always replacing yyy.php to say eee.php for redirect due to the introduction of a new file in the system. Unfortunately is simply replacing the file not an option.

This is probably basic knowledge for all who know their way around htaccess but I'm having a hard time figuring it out and the searches have not helped me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(yyy)\.php eee.php [L,R=301]
```

The R flag redirects, 301 means permanently.